# How do I disable tabs in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With the new version of Visual Studio Code, tabs are rendered by default. How do I disable / hide them as I really liked the previous behavior without any tabs?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

[Editor Tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tabs) make their appearance starting with Visual Studio Code version 1.3 (June 2016) and are enabled by default. To disable editor tabs:

1. Open Visual Studio Code *User Settings* (*Preferences* → *User Settings*). This will open two side-by-side documents.
2. Add a new `"workbench.editor.showTabs": false,` entry (if this is the last entry, omit the trailing comma).
3. Save the *User Settings* file.

Comment: To fully implement the previous behaviour: In addition to the above setting, set `workbench.editor.enablePreview` to `false` and `explorer.openEditors.visible` to `0`. This leaves you with a single editor window; _Ctrl+Tab_ displays the recently opened filse list; and the now redundant Explorer _OPEN EDITORS_ pane is hidden. I find this behaviour more focused and easier to use than a bunch of Tabs.

Comment: You can find more help in the migration issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6605

Comment: there is no User settings in Preference!!! i am using VS mac 7.3.3. any help is appreciated

Comment: Makes you wonder why they didn't make this part of View menu toggle white space or control characters. Or at least make this a menu item as it's quite core to the interface.

Answer (score 34):

Visual Studio Code v1.27+ now includes a [GUI for editing settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27#_settings-editor):

1. Open menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*.
2. Choose *User Settings* to apply everywhere (or *Workspace Settings* to turn off tabs on just this workspace).
3. Choose *Workbench* → *Editor Management* on the left, and then scroll down to *Show Tabs* and uncheck.

Alternatively, you could just pop into [Zen Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_zen-mode), which has tabs hidden by default.

Answer (score -11):

You can use  the plugin "Custom CSS & JS" and use the following code

```
.title.show-file-icons {
    display: none !important;
}
```