# VSCode showing only one file in the tab bar (can't open multiple files)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hit some shortcut and I can't find the setting the turn it off. But opening multiple files doesn't show different tabs.

Here's what I'm seeing

[image]

But this is what I'm expecting when I open a new tab

[image]

Comment: I had something where none of the files were showing when I'd open a folder. I posted question at: https://superuser.com/questions/1628804/why-does-visual-studio-code-vsc-display-nothing-when-i-open-a-folder-containin

Comment: I never though they will make me to search for solution on "How to open files in separate tabs in editor", in 2022. But here we are. Welcome to VS Code.

Comment: This is enough activity on this question that I filed a bug and they removed this binding for macOS, at least in the Insiders build! Hope it makes to release! 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147310

Comment: In case anyone finds this trying to figure out how to re-enable tabs, you actually do not need to change any options. Just double click the files to fully open them. Single clicks open the files in preview mode. See answers below to change the behavior, though.

Answer (score 621, accepted):

Check [User interface / Tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_tabs). You just need to add the following line in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": false
```

I also think that [How do I disable tabs in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147154/how-to-disable-tabs-in-vscode) is asking the exact opposite of what you are asking.

Comment: In VSCode, click Manage (is the gear shown at lower-left corner) > Settings > in the search bar on top type "showtabs" to get to the right menu > check-marked means tabs will show.

Comment: Seriously tired of finding such little hacks. Thank you very much. I don't understand why default setting is turned off? who on this earth do not want to see files in tabs?

Comment: @Atul On Mac, I found that accidentally pressing Ctrl + Cmd + W toggles this behavior and this was most likely what was hurting me as Ctrl + Cmd + Q is used to lock the screen. Maybe something similar is happening to you?

Comment: @ankush981That's exactly what I did; was trying to hit Shift-Cmd-W to close the window and fat-fingered it.

Comment: @ankush981 Thanks man pressing those keys again fixed it for me

Comment: Fixed using Ctrl + Cmd + W. Thanks

Comment: Can't believe false is the default

Comment: It seems my setting got changed maybe after upgrade. Because it worked well before. And suddenly, it failed to load more tabs. It is so weird.

Comment: Just in case the given solutions wont work, click on the elipses (...) in the editor window and select/enable "Keep Editors Open" option.

Comment: Previously, I already had "workbench.editor.showTabs": false within my settings.json. Despite so, the problem still exists. Not sure why. Instead, Echeban's answer worked for me.

Comment: This works "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false

Comment: I also posted this as an answer, but it appears many are still frustrated. If you still feel you have this problem it could be that "Preview Mode" is enabled. It is for me with every new installation of VS Code.

The title of the tab will be in italics, meaning it is in preview mode and the same tab will be used when you open the next file, unless you start modifying the file.

Go to settings and find "Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview" and deselect it. Now every file will be opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 589):

On a mac, if both of the existing answers didn't work, you can try command + ctrl + w, worked for me.

Comment: Works on windows too (ctrl + w)

Comment: Works on Linux as well (ctrl + w)

Comment: why does this work? what does this shortcut do? I worked for me too!

Comment: worked for me as well! probably pressing this key combo was the reason to disable the tabs somehow. cheers!

Comment: @DivyanshuKalra Yep, did the same thing I think. That's why I'm here, because I couldn't figure out why I was only getting one tab at a time. So annoying!

Comment: ...a disclaiming side note: this works only once. do not try to reproduce. I am now stuck back in single-tab mode

Comment: ...and a final update from me on this issue: try Reids answer instead. The setting "workbench > editor > enable preview" is documented as: "Controls whether opened editors show as preview. Preview editors are reused until they are pinned (e.g. via double click or editing) and show up with an italic font style."

Comment: @Superole It works always, I just checked, you can switch back and forth (between tabs and no tabs mode) as many time as you want on visual studio code.

Comment: @DivyanshuKalra maybe I was a bit hasty in my commenting. I meant to refer to the  Windows equivalent of your answer as mentioned by user2978241. I did not try your answer on a mac.

Comment: This keystroke corresponds to the command "View: Toggle Tab Visibility".  On a Mac, it is too similar to command+control+q, the system "Lock Screen" command (which is how I got here!)

Comment: I accidentally entered cmd + ctrl + w and I was going crazy what the hell happened. Until I saw your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, so this is what many of us who fell into this issue probably accidentally typed

Comment: I know this was the way I accidentally disabled my tabs as command + ctrl + q locks the screen, which I frequently use. It's very easy to hit the "W" instead of "Q".

Comment: Thanks man , it worked - tiny issue but was causing a lot of discomfort.

Answer (score 147):

The accepted answer didn't work for me for some reason. The answer given in [Open files always in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/how-to-config-vscode-to-open-files-always-in-a-new-tab) did.

In short: In the menu bar, click on *File > Preferences > Settings*. Then add the following line to the settings file.

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

Comment: Only this other question's answer solved it for me. In short: double-click (Open) rather than single-click (Preview).

Comment: This just saved me from not being able to compare scripts! Thank you!

Comment: This is the only answer that worked. Maybe it worked in combination of other ones.

Comment: My VSCode literally just started doing this without warning. This answer fixed it but not sure what changed in the last 2 minutes!

Comment: https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2020/01/change-vscode-preview-files/ offers good explanations and debugging tips.

Answer (score 142):

try <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> in Mac, it works fine

Comment: @ItayElgazar I saw this answer, muttered "Thank god" to myself, then saw your comment :D

Comment: works also on ubunto : [command(windows button)] + CTRL +W

Comment: praise the lords for thy answer

Comment: How do cats always mange to hit crazy shortcuts like this

Comment: For me, I meant to press `control + command + Q to lock my screen`, but hit W accidentally.

Answer (score 32):

This feature is toggled with the command “View: Toggle Tab Visibility”.
Internally, it is known as `workbench.action.toggleTabsVisibility`.

On **MacOS**, the default keybinding is `command + control + w`, which is dangerously close to the OS’s "Lock Screen" command `command + control + q`.  (Hitting this accidentally while trying to lock my screen is how I got here!)

On **Linux**, the default keybinding is `meta + control + w`

On **Windows**, the keybinding used to be `win + control + w`, but it looks like they removed it.  See these github issues:

- [Windows key in default keybindings on Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67695)
- [Add toggleTabsVisibility to keybinding actions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30314#issuecomment-459683262)

Comment: Most important keys 

Control+CMD+W 

for enabling, multiple tabs

Answer (score 25):

By mistake i tap on mac ctrl + command + w button on visual studio code then open file tabs hide.

Then i tap same button Ctrl+ Cmd + w then its again shows

Answer (score 22):

VSCode Extension: [Wrap Console Log](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=midnightsyntax.vscode-wrap-console-log) use `Ctrl + Alt + W` to wrap

VSCode use `^ + ⌘ + W` to Toggle Tab Visiblity

VSCode use `⇧ + ⌘ + W` to Close Window

---

It's easy to make mistakes .

Comment: ^ + ⌘ + W yes pressed this by mistakes 

Comment: I meant to press `control + command + Q` to lock my screen, but hit W accidentally.

Answer (score 20):

As of the most recent update, in my VSC, you have to ***double-click the file icon*** to get a new tab.

And this just when I was finally getting used to clicking ONCE in the older version.  I mean, I get "push out a new feature set ASAP" if Microsoft wants to compete with F/OSS, but haven't they heard of [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) ... and not breaking it?

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me insane.

Comment: Digging a bit more, this is called "Preview Editors". The description is "Controls whether editors opened from Quick Open show as preview. Preview editors are reused until they are pinned (e.g. via double click or editing)." Preview editors show with an italic font.

Looking in settings, the two options are Workbench > Editor > "Enable Preview From Quick Open" and "Enable Preview".

Answer (score 18):

On VsCode version 1.64.2 , do the following :

1. Open VsCode settings and search for "Show Tabs", like shown in this screen shot:[image]
2. Check and select the option for "Show Tabs" as pointed.

Answer (score 12):

This is a "feature" albeit a confusing one of Visual Studio code called the "Preview" tab!

I know I struggled with it until I took the time out and searched here for an answer!.

Normally you can ***single-click*** on a file and open it in a preview tab, go over it and move on to the next one. This can be handy when you've opened a folder and quickly want to go through the files therein.

However, it is confusing when you're actually **working** on files. The simplest solution is to ***double-click*** on a file in the explorer tab, this opens up the file in it's own ***separate tab***.

IMHO, an alternate approach to disabling the feature, is getting used to this "default" setting of a preview tab,  rather than turning it off in settings and later on, when you re-install it or go to another machine,  struggling with "Ahh...I knew I did something to disable this behaviour!".

If this thought process doesn't work for you, you can always do what's suggested in the other answers.

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. This should be at the top. Visual Studio Code does not make it obvious that a tab is a preview tab, so most users will not realize that is what's happening. I certainly didn't. No options need changed. Just have to actually "open" the file!

Answer (score 11):

If you still feel you have this problem it could be that "Preview Mode" is enabled. The title of the tab will be in italics, meaning it is in preview mode and the same tab will be used when you open the next file, unless you start modifying the file.

Go to settings and find "Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview" and deselect it. Now every file will be opened in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

For mac, if your tab close icon disappears and showing every page in a new tab just press (as shown in image).

[image]

```
Command + Control + W
```

or

```
⌘ + ^ + W
```

It will appear your tab icons (as shown in the picture).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Go to **Preferences** -> **Settings** -> **UserSettings** -> **Workbench** -> **EditorManagement**
check "**Show Tabs**" . Tabs will appear immediately .Enjoy

Answer (score 10):

Follow this,

```
Go to Preferences -> Settings -> UserSettings -> Workbench -> EditorManagement
check "Show Tabs"
```

and Restart,
Enjoy (y)

Answer (score 9):

**File** > **Preferences** > **Settings**

Search **editor enable preview** on search bar, **Disable Enable** Preview option (Just untick or set false).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was the issue! These "preview" windows are obnoxious in that even if you make a change, they periodically vanish.

Answer (score 8):

This error happens because workbench.editor.showTabs is set to false. Open the Settings.json Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and then type `Open Setting` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

In the settings.json file add this line at the bottom.

`"workbench.editor.showTabs": true`

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with setting `workbench.editor.showTabs:true`.Just double click on the file you want open in new tab and it will VS Code will open it for you in new tab.

Comment: It seems the double click is the trick here. A single click opens the file in an existing tab

Answer (score 6):

In latest visual studio code , by double clicking on any of the file in file explorer will open in new tab.
It assumes single click as a file preview option and many people get confused with it.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's the property `"workbench.editor.showTabs": true`.
I had the same problem and I just changed this setting to true.

Answer (score 5):

In short: double-click (Open) rather than single-click

Answer (score 5):

I don't like preference options or config files - until recently I preferred the  double click file name solution ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322272/5704347)).. but in **version 1.71 (August 2022)** there's  a handy menu option for it on the upper right ... uncheck it and every file will load in a separate tab..

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```

Answer (score 3):

In *vscode* ,click on *file>preferance>setting*.
In *setting*, there would be a **search-bar**.
There, you have to search `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`.
Then you will get one option with checked-box.
If it is already checked then you mark it as unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a new feature in VS Code, When you are opening a new project and skimming through the code file by file, each file will get replaced in the same tab, Whilst if you do some changes in a file and save it, and try opening a new file it will open in a new file.

May be it is trying to do some kind of tab clean up by restricting the user to open multiple tabs and restricting them to use multiple tabs only when they need to edit the files in them.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Settings (Ctrl + ,)
Type 'workbench.editor'
Click Checkbox on
Controls whether opened editors...
your problem is solved

[image: workbench editor in vss]

Answer (score 2):

In VSCode, click Manage (is the gear shown at lower-left corner) > Settings >

in the search bar on top type "showtabs" , do below 2 changes

1. Workbench › Editor: Show Tabs = checked
2. Workbench › Editor: Tab Sizing = shrink

Answer (score 1):

On a mac and maybe other OSs you can double click on the filename to pin the file open in the editor. This way, you can selectively choose which files you want to remain open in the VS Code editor.

Answer (score 0):

you need edit setting.json file,

settings.json, located at

```
Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json


        {
          "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
          "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case editor limit is set to true in `settings.json`, change it to false value

`"workbench.editor.limit.enabled": false`

If you want to allow only maximum of 5 tabs to open you can set

```
"workbench.editor.limit.enabled": true,
"workbench.editor.limit.value": 5,
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of your `workbench.editor.showTabs`. You may have set it to `"single"` or `"none"`. The default value is `"multiple"`. This setting doesn't actually prevent multiple tabs from being opened in an editor group. It just changes how many are displayed in the tab bar. You can still switch between the editors in the editor group by using <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>page up/down</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. Note that in older version of VS Code, it was a boolean, and you'd be checking if you set it to `false`.

Also check if you've set `workbench.editor.limit.enabled` to `true` and `workbench.editor.limit.value` to `1`. This would *actually* limit the number of opened editors in an editor group to 1.

If the tab title is italicized, then the problem may just be that it's a preview tab, in which case you should really be reading [How can I prevent VS Code from replacing a newly opened, unmodified (preview) tab with a subsequently opened one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38713405/11107541). TL;DR you can double click in the Explorer to open in non-preview, or double-click the editor's tab handle, or save the file, or press enter after clicking in the Explorer, or disable editor previews using the `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false` setting.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I just changed the following settings inside visual studio 2017.

> Tools > Environment > Tabs and windows

[visual studio 2017 view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIhpU.png)

Answer (score -1):

go to preferences > workbench > enable preview,
or just open preferences and search 'preview', mark as true.

Answer (score -1):

Go to keyboard shortcuts and search for covert indent to tabs-> by default there won't be any shortcut assigned to it, you have to assign it and then run the shortcut. It will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

quick fix, click on the page you want to display in another tab next to it and drag it there and it will revert back to its normal ways of opening each page as a new tab.

my reference is i did it now so i decided to sign up here hoping to make things easier for anyone having this problem.

Answer (score -1):

To enable multiple files opened in vscode editor:

```
Settings -> Workspace -> Multi-File Diff Editor -> Enable experimental multi diff editor
```

Note:

- This works on Visual Studio Code:

```
Version: 1.85.1 (Universal)
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:48:06.308Z (3 wks ago)
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.6.0
```