# How can multiple files be opened in Visual Studio Code (VSC)?

Tags: windows, html, css, visual-studio-code

How can multiple files be opened in Visual Studio Code (VSC)?

For some reason, my copy of Visual Studio Code can only open one file at a time. For example, if there are two files in the workspace folder, let’s say an HTML and CSS file, both cannot be opened simultaneously. If one file is open, clicking any other item in VSC's file explorer will replace the current file. VSC will not open the other file in a new editing tab.

I am not concerned with running multiple instances, Workspaces or folders of VSC. I just want to open two files in the same folder. Is there a configuration setting controlling this? Or is this the result of upgrading to the latest version of VSC? Is just a "new feature" of VSC?

It's seems ridiculously simple, but I need help. I am running Visual Studio Code v. 1.24.0 for [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) 64 bit.

Visual Studio Code screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode showing only one file in the tab bar (can't open multiple files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589785/vscode-showing-only-one-file-in-the-tab-bar-cant-open-multiple-files)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, in the linked issue tabs were entirely disabled. The described problem explains only the fact that single-clicking VSCode files does not open a new tab.

Comment: I never though they will make me to search for solution on "How to open files in separate tabs in editor", in 2022. But here we are. Welcome to VS Code.

Answer (score 78):

In Visual Studio Code, if you click once on a file, it opens it in a temporary tab. This is helpful if you are looking into a bunch of files searching for something, without opening every single one of them.

If you want to open a file in a new tab that persists until closed manually, **double-click** on the file.

You can also persist a tab that was previously created as a temporary tab by double-clicking on the tab. Note that temporary tabs have an italicized title, while normal tabs do not.

Comment: The file will also remain open if you make edits of any kind to it. But if you're looking to open several from the get-go, double clicking is the way to go.

Comment: If you're a keyboard user (I open files using ctrl+P), go to the "possible duplicate" question referenced above and see the answer with `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`

Comment: Seriously, who are guys behind these decisions? It's really painful to search for all the forums on the Internet for plain simple intuitive thing which works in thousands of other similar applications. Many thanks for your answer. It's "double click".

Comment: @Atul, the same hermits who came up with the Git UI, with the secret agenda of turning StackOverflow into a [crooked temple dedicated to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Shame on whoever decided this was a sane default.

Answer (score 31):

Others have mentioned double-clicking the file in order to open it, however, I will suggest an alternative approach:

Within your settings, under workbench, set:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
```

This will allow you to open the files with a single click, as opposed to double-clicking. It may seem minute, but it was incredibly annoying to have to double-click every single file.

Comment: this is the right way.

Comment: What is "your settings"? A JSON file? Something else?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `,` (comma)? Or something else?

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio Code, by default, keeps this option enabled to open a file in a temporary file. This feature comes in handy when you want to just take a look at some code.

If you want to open a file in a new tab, just **double click** on the tab or double click on the folder you want to open from explorer or once the file is opened press the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

You can even disable this option in menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*, under the user settings.

Paste this code in your user's setting.

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": false
```

Answer (score 8):

Please follow below steps:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*.  Now you will see USER SETTINGS and WORKSPACE SETTINGS.

Click on **WORKSPACE SETTINGS**.  Now search for **workbench.editor.showTabs** and change its value to **true**.

I tested this by turning it false and it restricts from opening multiple files in tabs. When it's false, whenever you open one file, only that file will be opened and the earlier file gets closed.

When set to true, you can open as many files you want and all files will be a new tab.

Answer (score 6):

Go to 'settings' in Visual Studio Code and search for 'preview'. Then on the second position from the top you will find "Workbench › Editor: Enable Preview". Simply untick it and your problem will be solved.

In [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFdHl.gif) you can see it's working properly.

Comment: Re *"Go to 'settings'"*: *How* exactly?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `,` (comma)? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click and highlight all the files in the sidebar, then you can click and drag them all to whatever area of the editor you want.

[image: Visual Studio Code open multiple files]

Comment: Thanks. With those selected files, I tried Right click or Ctrl-Shift-P, but unable to open them all in the first editor group. I didn't know I can drag!

Answer (score 3):

Try the three dots on the upper right hand side corner, right beside the icon for splitting the editor.

From the drop down, check if the option **keep editors open** is enabled. If not, enable it.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 2):

Just double-click on files to open in new tab.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to *Setting*
- type 'json' in the search box
- under 'Launch', click on "edit in setting json"
- then change the *workbench.editor* from *false* to *true* shown below.

  ```
  "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": true
  ```

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where a screenshot would be appropriate (unlike for text/code).

Comment: Does it actually say *"edit in setting json"*? Not *"Edit in settings.json"*?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code, open settings (command ,) on mac, search for "showTabs" and select "multiple".

Comment: Re *"open settings"*: *How* exactly? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57858856/edit), not here in comments (******* ***without*** ******* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: `Ctrl` + `,` (comma)? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

**Double-click on the file** and it will be opened permanently in the Visual Studio window until closed manually.

If you single click on the file, then the file can be replaceable if some other file is opened.

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio"*: Do you mean *"[Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)"*? They are not the same thing (thanks, Microsoft marketing).

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes I meant Visual Studio Code only :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1. Double-click on the file. (*or*)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and single-click on the file.