# I cant open multiple files at once in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: Here is the image]

Here i am not able to open multiple files 
[image]

Here while I try to open a different file it open it but replaces it with the  file opened earlier

**Like at previous I opened file [Multiples_of_7(while_loop).py]
Then when i click at a different file to open it 
It simply replaces it with the previous file I opened **

> I dont know what is the problem as it always opened each file separately in new tab before 
>   Please help

Comment: This not a Python question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827846/how-can-multiple-files-be-opened-in-visual-studio-code-vsc already answered here.

Comment: Sorry didn't realised that i was posting it in python section and also thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the preview function try changing out the value of  `workbench.editor.enablePreview` in the settings.json file, to `true`.