VS Code "goto definition" closes the current file
VS Code changed its behavior when it comes to "goto definition" (F12 or alt+click on mac).
Right now (Version: 1.89.1 (Universal)) it closes the current file opens the one with the reference in it (temporarily = name in tab italic).
It was that the editor would just open the ref in another tab and I could close it and be back where I left of ... when did this change? And more importantly: how do I revert this? Couldn't find the right setting.
And this is not about "preview tabs", the current file is no preview like mentioned in this question.
I have
{
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
}

in my settings but it still happens. And more importantly wasn't happening before ‍♂️

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48589785/11107541. see my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77789957/11107541

@super-starball-ultra it was showing multiple, not just one. so not exactly the same problem/reason

Ok, found the setting that was causing my "problems".
It was the workbench.editor.limit.value - it was set to 6 
But I never changed this. I changed it to 20 and now everything is back to how it was before (for me)

Or you could disable this completely with the workbench.editor.limit.enabled setting - just disable it and no tabs are closed automatically.

